# Why is this happening with int?

Tags: java

I observed that in Java when I do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 45;
    int j = 045;

    System.out.println("i:>>"+i);
    System.out.println("j:>>"+j);
}
```

The output is:

```
i:>>45
j:>>37
```

Why this is happening? The value of `j` is printed as `37` when it is `45`?

Could anybody please guide? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Leading zero implies that the number is being considered as octal.

Comment: its a basic of any programming language..any number starts with 0 is considered to be an octal number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`045` is an octal (base `8`):

```
8^2 * 0 + 8^1 * 4 + 5 = 37
```

`45` is a decimal (base `10`).

---

Try running this:

```
int j = 049;
System.out.println("j:>>" + j);
```

you will get *"The literal 049 of type int is out of range"*, because octal numbers can just have digits from `0` to `7`(this is why it is base `8`).

**Edit:**

As @Gleen mentioned in a comment, an hexadecimal is leading by `0x`:

```
int j = 0x111; // 16^2 * 1 + 16^1 * 1 + 1 = 273
System.out.println("j:>>" + j);
```

<sub>**Output:**</sub>

```
j:>>273
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [Java Language Specification, section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

Quoting:

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

```
OctalNumeral:
    0 OctalDigits
    0 Underscores OctalDigits

OctalDigits:
    OctalDigit
    OctalDigit OctalDigitsAndUnderscoresopt OctalDigit 

OctalDigit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

OctalDigitsAndUnderscores:
    OctalDigitOrUnderscore
    OctalDigitsAndUnderscores OctalDigitOrUnderscore

OctalDigitOrUnderscore:
    OctalDigit
    _
```

As you'll find if you read the specification, Java also supports several other integer notations, such as hexadecimal (prefix with `0x`), and binary (prefix with `0b`), as well as plain decimal (no prefix).

Answer (score 1):

When you prefix a literal number in Java with `0`, it is treated as an octal value (base 8).

Octal `45` equals `37` in base `10`.